# Custom code for gesture everywhere it's used?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

For simplicity, assume I want to log every time a specific longpress gesture is triggered, but I don't want to have the log code in every selector the gesture might target. I want to have the code in one place, preferably right in a subclass of the specific gesture so when it enters its began state, the log code is executed.

How would one go about this for a subclass of a gesture?

The only way I know how is to override the initWithTarget method of the gesture, store the target/action specified in a NSInvocation object, replace the target/action with my logging code and have my logging code invoke the stored NSInvocation object when it is done. Kind of a man-in-the-middle technique. I'm really not fond of this implementation, it seems quite hacky.

Edit: This is for a longpress gesture. I did not know of UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h, but now that I do, touchesBegan triggers before the gesture is recognized. How do I specifically watch for the gesture being recognized? Overriding setState seems to work, but waiting for the recognized state won't trigger until after the action is triggered.

Comment: Just make a subclass.

Comment: How about you put logging code in a singleton file and then use that in your subclass, respective `touchesBegan` method. That way, your logging code is in one object and you will be always calling that.

Comment: @adev I should have clarified that this is for a longpress gesture. I need to look for the gesture being recognized, not just when touchesBegan triggers. When testing this using touchesBegan, if you tap quickly, it is logged without having the action triggered.

Comment: Please see the edit of the original post related to overriding setState.

Answer (score 0):

Two pieces were unknown to me when I asked this question.

1. Importing UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h would override state read/write instead of only read.
2. touchesBegan, which is also only overridable after importing UIGestureRecognizerSubclass, is just for the touch itself. The proper way to watch for the gesture itself to enter the state began is to override the state's setter.

Answer: Import UIGestureRecognizerSubclass and override the state's setter. By doing this, you can execute your own code before the gesture call's on it's target selector.

Example:

```
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

-(void)setState:(UIGestureRecognizerState)state
{
    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        analyticsForStealthViewRevealElement(self);
    }
    else
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    [super setState:state];
}
```